# Regex to look for cyber squatting or spoofing?

Tags: regex, yara

I am trying to create a bit of regex that matches any deviation of the domain “example.com”.

Finding characters before or after “example” is easy enough. Finding deviations of “example” is where it gets challenging for me.

I could do something like `[^e][^x][^a][^m][^p][^l][^e]`, but then every character has to be deviated. If I place a `?` after each bracketed group, “x.com” now matches.

I need the expression to match a deviation but not match “example”.

I am doing this within the context of a YARA rule, so lookaround is not available.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *deviation*?

Comment: Can't you just match example.com and use the `!=` operator?

Comment: I think you need to come up with a formal definition for "deviation" before you can search for them. For example I assume you would consider "exemple" to be a deviation because it is the same length and different by only one letter. But is "exaample" a deviation? How about "ample" or "hexample" or "uxumplu"?